# Entities' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

```
public class Connection
{
    public static string GetConecction()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DCAssetEntities"].ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

I have one "connection" class to configure my web  with Entity framework model Entities

```
public class ConnectionDAL
{
    private DCAssetEntities db;

    public ConnectionDAL()
    {
        db = new DCAssetEntities(Connection.GetConecction());
    }
}
```

then I intialize my database in "ConnectionDAL" class constructor,, It's working good in Visusal Studio 2010 but in visusal Studio 2012 showing Error "DC_Asset_Maintenance.DAL.DCAssetEntities' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments
"

Comment: do you have DCAssetEntities connection string in the website web.config?

Comment: yes........i have DCAssetEntities connection string in the website web.config

Comment: Can you show the constructor(s) for DCAssetEntities

Comment: public ConnectionDAL()
    {
        db = new DCAssetEntities(Connection.GetConecction());
    } Iam using this constructor in ConnectionDAL Class

Comment: but this line is creating 'DCAssetEntities' -> db = new DCAssetEntities(Connection.GetConecction()); and you don't have a ctor in this class that takes one argument

Comment: I am using the same code in Visual Studio 2010, doing well but it's only asking for constructor argument...... :( kindly guide me how to create constructor for one argument...as i m not much experienced in Entity framework

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34168/discussion-between-hamid-and-christiandev)

Comment: Try this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462319/entity-connection-string-constructor-not-found-in-ef-5-and-wcf-4-5-at-runtime][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462319/entity-connection-string-constructor-not-found-in-ef-5-and-wcf-4-5-at-runtime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your class `DCAssetEntities` needs to have a constructor with the following definition.

```
public DCAssetEntities(string connectionString){}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the constructor yourself in a partial class:

```
public partial class DCAssetEntities: DbContext
{
    public DCAssetEntities(string connectionstring)
        : base(connectionstring)
    {
    }
}
```

Related question:
[Entity Connection String Constructor not found in EF 5 and WCF 4.5 at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462319/entity-connection-string-constructor-not-found-in-ef-5-and-wcf-4-5-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the constructor as `public` (or  `internal`).

Comment: I'm referring to DCAssetEntities