# EF6 Change connection string at runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I created a EDMX file from DB:

```
internal partial class LocalBDD : DbContext
{
    public LocalBDD() : base("name=LocalBDD")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<C__RefactorLog> C__RefactorLog { get; set; }
}
```

If I store the connection string in `App.config`, this works fine, but I need to encrypt the sensitive info, I'm trying to change the connection from my context in this way:

```
LocalBDD _localBDD;
_localBDD = new LocalBDD("my new connStr");
```

But I get

> LocalBDD does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

This code it's generated by the ADO.NET Entity Data Model Assitant, and if I edit it for add a constructor which takes 1 argument, when the project recompile the changes will be lose.

How I can change the connection string of my DbContext at runtime?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entities' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861570/entities-does-not-contain-a-constructor-that-takes-1-arguments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend that you read some basic C# tutorials on classes and constructors, which would help you understand the error you are receiving.

Your `LocalBDD` class constructor only takes one argument.  If you want to be able to pass in connection string information, you need to either expand your current constructor or add an additional constructor with a string argument:

```
public LocalBDD()
    : base("name=LocalBDD")
{
}

public LocalBDD(string connectionString)
    : base(connectionString)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it raises my question wrong, I really want to know why the assistant visual studio generates this code, when compiling rewrites and does not retain changes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on David's response I created a separate .cs file and wrote in this a partial class to prevent the overwriting:

```
public partial class LocalBDD : DbContext
{
    public LocalBDD(string connetionString)
        : base(connetionString)
    {
    }
}
```

However I´m not sure this is the better way. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: Using partial class is the best way to do this, as the 2 files would be merged  together into a single file at runtime, so you have the 2 constructors in a single file. Visual studio make changes to the generated dbContext class every time you update your context and any changes to the dbContext class will be wiped out. So creating a partial class prevents you from losing the changes you made